# How do I know the id before saving an object in jpa

Tags: java, oracle, jpa, jpa-2.0

I have a new object. I want to know id before saving it. Is it possible? Or there is another way for this? I am using jpa as orm and oracle as database.

```
@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "woTypeSeq")
private Long id;
```

I have a code field in my entity. If the user doesn't enter a value for the `code` field, I want to set code as entity's id. If I persist entity, of course i can get id and set code value as id, but this is extra query database.

I want to do something like that

```
if(entity.getCode()==null) {
   entity.setCode(entity.getId);
   jpaDao.saveOrUpdate(entity);
}
```

Comment: You could avoid the @GeneratedValue, use the generator yourself to get the value and set it to entity "manually"

Comment: I dont want to set it to entity manually.if i get next value for id from oracle and i set it to new entity's id,is it rational ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After long researching about this, finally I found a solution.

In fact, if you use ***sequence generator*** in jpa, certainly you cannot obtain entity's id before saving it in database, because next id will be assigned by database sequence.

There is one way to obtain the id if you use a ***custom generator***, you can get the id before saving. Here is simple implementation:

```
public class CustomGenerator extends IdentityGenerator implements Configurable {

    private IdentifierGenerator defaultGenerator;

    public Serializable generate(SessionImplementor session, Object object) throws HibernateException {
        Long idValue = (Long)defaultGenerator.generate(session, object);
        //idValue will be assigned your entity id
        return idValue;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(Type type, Properties params, Dialect d) throws MappingException {
        DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory dd = new DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory();
        dd.setDialect(d);
        defaultGenerator = dd.createIdentifierGenerator("sequence", type, params);
    }
}
```

Using CustomGenerator for id field:

```
@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
@GenericGenerator(name = "seq_id", strategy = "com.yoncabt.abys.core.listener.CustomGenerator", parameters = { @Parameter(name = "sequence", value = "II_FIRM_DOC_PRM_SEQ") })
@GeneratedValue(generator = "seq_id")
private Long id;
```

Comment: Would you please tell me the package of Configurable interface?
I see a lots of package contains this but none of those has a method 

configure(Type type, Properties params, Dialect d) throws MappingException {}

Comment: could this ID be used in prepersist ??

Answer (score 14):

With a @GeneratedValue type id you can't know that value in advance (before actually writing it). However once you persist your Bean, the id field will be populated in that bean instance and you can obtain it without needing to do an extra query for it. In other words:

```
MyEntiry myEnt = new MyEntity(); //the id field is null now
entityManager.persist(myEnt);//the id field is populated in myEnt now
Long id = myEnt.getId();
```

Also, depending on how your `EntityManager` is configured, you might need to also first commit the transaction (manually) before you can get that id.

## Update as per comment

If you want to intercept and do something to the entity before it is saved and/or updated, you can use JPA LifeCycle Listeners (if you're using JPA version 2): [Handling JPA lifecycle event using listeners and callbacks](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/event).

Basically you can make a `validate()` method in your bean, annotate it with  `@PrePersist` and `@PreUpdate` and do the validation in it (if code is empty set it to id's value)

## Update per 2nd comment

Yes, I honestly just thought of that just now: that if the id is auto generated, it might get populated AFTER the pre-persist event, such that when your pre-persist code is executed you still don't know what the id is (you may notice also that in the example you link to the id is NOT autogenerated but set manually).
What you can do in this case is add a boolean field to your entity (annotated with `@Transient` so it won't get persisted) called `isCodeEmpty` (which is false by default if not specifically initialized). Then in your `@PrePersist` annotated method you check if the value for code field is empty and if so, set the boolean to true. Then you refactor your `setId(...)` method such that (aside from setting the id field) it will check this boolean, and if true set the value of the code field to that of the id field:

```
public class YourEntity {

@Transient
private boolean isCodeEmpty;

public void setId(Whatever id) {
 this.id = id;
 if(isCodeEmpty) {
  this.code = id;
  //if necessary:
  //this.isCodeEmpty = false;
 }
}

@PrePersist
public void validate() {
 if(code == null || code.isEmpty()) {
  isCodeEmpty = true;
 }

}


}
```

Comment: Thank you for replying.I updated my question.Can you check it ?

Comment: I have tried entity listener.but in prepersist id value is null.I dont know why it is null.I implements like that = http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0355__JPA/EntityListenersPrePersist.htm        do you have suggestion or idea ? Thank you very much

Comment: your idea is excellent but after prePersist setId() method not working.I did  what you say. I debugging it,but setId method not executed and code field dont set.Prepersist is working.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the solution that works for me:

```java
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "my_seq" )
    @SequenceGenerator( name = "my_seq", sequenceName = "my_seq" )
    @Access( AccessType.PROPERTY )
    private Long id;

    @Column( name = "CODE", nullable = false, updatable = false )
    private Long code;

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
        if (code == null) {
            code = id;
        }
    }
```

The important part is placing the `@javax.persistence.Access( AccessType.PROPERTY )` annotation, which makes Hibernate use the getter and the setter to access the id field. Without it, when the @Id annotation placed directly on a field rather than on the field getter, Hibernate uses a field-based access strategy (getter and setter are not used). Link:
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#access

Comment: Minor tweaking:

`if (code == null && id != null) { ... }`

Comment: The link provided is no longer available. However, you can find the current link here: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html

Comment: Thank you for replying! JohnW, everyone will choose what they like best. I'd rather consider making the setter private. CODI, Link updated.

Answer (score 0):

Just follow these steps then you will get the id before you complete the transaction.

1st step adds an entity listener at your entity level by using the annotation called `@EntityListeners`.

```
@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "woTypeSeq")
@EntityListeners(SomeLinstener.class)
private Long id;
```

2nd step

```
public class SomeLinstener{
    
    @PostPersist
    public void userPostPersist(YourEntity obj) {
        
        try {
            obj.getId();
        }catch(Exception e) {
            
        }
    }
```

This will you an id which has been generated by your generator and you can reuse where ever it is required this will give in a single transaction.

Hope this will help for somebody else.