# Spring REST - Proper PUT functionality when resource does not already exist

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, put

I am building a REST API using Spring and implementing the PUT functionality. I am trying to handle the scenario in which the client tries to PUT to a uri where the resource does not already exist. In this scenario, per the PUT spec, a new resource should be created at that ID. However because of the ID generation strategy I am using (`@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)`), I cannot create resources with IDs out of sequence. The database must use the next available value. However, according to the w3 spec on PUT...

> If the Request-URI does not point to an existing resource, and that URI is capable of being defined as a new resource by the requesting user agent, the origin server can create the resource with that URI.
>
> If the server desires that the request be applied to a different URI, it MUST send a 301 (Moved Permanently) response; the user agent MAY then make its own decision regarding whether or not to redirect the request.

In this case, I can do neither of these. I cannot create a new resource at the existing URI due to the ID generation restrictions, and I cannot send a 301 Moved Permanently response because according to [How do I know the id before saving an object in jpa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12742826/how-do-i-know-the-id-before-saving-an-object-in-jpa) it is impossible to know the next ID in a sequence before actually persisting the object. So I would have no way of telling the client what URI to redirect to in order to properly create the new resource.

I would imagine this problem has been solved many times over because it is the standard PUT functionality, yet I am having trouble finding any other people who have tried to do this. It seems most people just ignore the "create new resource" part of PUT, and simply use it as update only.

What I want to do is just go ahead and create the new resource, and then send the 301 Moved Permanently to redirect the client to the true location of the created resource - but as we see above, this violates the definition of PUT.

Is there a spring-y way to solve this problem? Or is the problem unsolved, and the *true* standard practice is to simply not allow creation of new resources via PUT?

Comment: show an error in such case.

Answer (score 1):

If the server cant processes the request due to an error in the request, just return a 400.

> 400 Bad Request -
>   The server cannot or will not process the request due to an apparent client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, size too large, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing).