# Update the JPA entity in PostPersist event method

Tags: java, jpa, persistence

I want to update the entity in `@PostPersist` method in order to get the generated ID and put it in another column in the same table :

```
@PostPersist
public void postPersist(Customer customer) {
   customer.setCode("Code_" + customer.getId);
}
```

This update is not persisted in the DataBase. So what I should do to update my entity using the String "Code_" appended to the generated Id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@PostPersit` and `@PrePersist` are callback methods. They are executed after the JPA transaction.
In your case you could:

1. Set `code`  manualy after `persist` method and make another request for saving of customer with this `code`
2. You can leave the `@PostPersist` annotation, but in this case you also need another save request
3. If you are using `custom generator`, you could get `id` before saving ([How do I know the id before saving an object in jpa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12742826/how-do-i-know-the-id-before-saving-an-object-in-jpa))

[Code example](https://github.com/volodya-lombrozo/stackoverflow_64487971)

Comment: I'll go for the third choice, thanks a lot @Volodya